# Задачка на пересечения

Tags: php, mysql

**Данные:** Имеется ассоциативная таблица связей групп и студентов, содержащая поля group_id & student_id (один студент может быть в нескольких группах, так и одна группа может содержать нескольких студентов).

**Задача:** Необходимо составить списки групп, в которых имеются общие студенты (список общих студентов не важен, но будет плюсом, если возможно также получить).

**Вывод результатов:** выводить строками, каждая из которых будет содержать  полный список идентификаторов групп, а в конце строки в скобках общее количество студентов (можно также в квадратных скобках выводить список идентификаторов общих студентов). Строки выводить до тех. пор, пока в ней содержится более 1-й группы.

**П.С.:** Задачу можно решать любым способом. Желательно mysql+php. Надеюсь, с условием не напутал.

**UPD:** Задачка похоже с правилами форума немного не вяжется, поэтому поправка - мне нужен лишь намек на решение. Ну и может мой скилл, долго и упорно зарабатываемый на этом проекте, подтверит мое "совершеннолетие" и откинет подозрения о том, что это вопрос от студента для решения курсовой.

**UPD 2:** Привожу пример данных и что должно получится. Имеются группы g1, g2, g3 и студенты s1, s2, s3. Студент s1 состоит во всех группах. s2 в g1 & g3, s3 в g1 & g2. Мы должны получить:

```
g1, g2 (2)
g1, g3 (2)
```

Соответсвенно в таблице такие записи:

```
g1 s1
g2 s1
g3 s1
g1 s2
g3 s2
g1 s3
g2 s3
```

Comment: @org, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @kite, Я не учащийся. Просто не могу решить эту задачку. Идеи все в лоб с рекурсией и не для продакшен версий. group_id и student_id вымышленные, так как работодатель не хочет раскрывать коммерческой тайны.

Answer (score 2):

Запросом:

```
SELECT group_id
FROM table_name
WHERE
    student_id IN (
        SELECT student_id
        FROM table_name
        GROUP BY 1
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
GROUP BY 1
```

можно выбрать все группы где есть пересекающиеся студенты

**UPD:** Список студентов, которые сразу в нескольких группах:

```
SELECT student_id
FROM table_name
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Развейте мои сомнения, но мне кажется это не верное решение. Подзапросом мы вытащим всех студентов, которые состоят более чем в одной группе. А на внешнем мы проверяем, есть ли у данной группы студент в этом списке. В итоге мы получим группы, которые имеют по студенту, который состоит более чем в одной группе. Но по условию нам надо найти списки групп, у которых общие студенты. Хотя, вчитываясь в фразу "можно выбрать все группы где есть пересекающиеся студенты" , запрос верен.

Comment: Ну да. Именно так запрос и работает.

Если студент более чем в одной группе, значит, все группы в которых он состоит имеют, по крайней мере, одного общего студента.

Или нужны группы, в которых перечень студентов совпадает полностью?

Comment: Да, полностью.

Comment: Тогда можно отталкиваться от запроса:

    SELECT group_id, MD5(GROUP_CONCAT(student_id ORDER BY 1)) AS crc
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 2

`GROUP_CONCAT` - агрегатная функция. В данном случае она выведет упорядоченный список `student_id` через запятую в одну строку по каждой группе. `MD5()` посчитает контрольную сумму каждой такой строки. Те группы, где `MD5()` совпадают и есть группы с одинаковым набором студентов. Можно сразу сравнивать результат от `GROUP_CONCAT()`, просто уменьшит сравниваемые строки до 32 символов.

Comment: Спасибо за group_concat. Есть опять подозрения: Если мы будем сравнивать md5 хеш, то мы получим список групп у которых все принадлежащие ей студенты принадлежат и другой группе. А что если из первой группы 3 студента  только состоят во всех других группах - в этом случае ничего не получим таким сравнением.

Comment: Поэтому я и спрашивал:

> Или нужны группы, в которых перечень студентов совпадает полностью?

И в ответ услышал:

> Да, полностью.

По хешам можно вычислить те группы, где перечень студентов совпадает полностью. Тоесть: Группа1(Иванов,Петров,Сидоров) и Группа2(Иванов,Петров,Сидоров) - совпадают. А Группа3(Иванов,Петров,Сидоров,Рабинович) - не совпадет ни с Группа1 ни с Группа2.

Но тогда мне непонятно условие. Если ни вариант с общими студентами не подходит, ни - с полностью совпадающим списком.

Comment: В вашем примере должен вывести группа1, группа2, группа3 (Иванов Петров Сидоров)

Answer (score 2):

Из таблицы получаем следующее

```
Dictionary<group_id, List<student_id>>
```

далее нам необходимо пересечь список студентов групп между группами,
здесь получается перебор всех подмножеств множества групп
цикл от `0` до `2^n-1`,
конечно, единичные множества не учитываются,
пересекаете множества список студентов, если нулевое то данное подмножество групп отсеиваете.

Можете пользоваться предыдущими результатами вычислений пересечений групп, дабы одно и тоже не считать.

Comment: только PHP этот для таких задач не особо то годится

Comment: Идея хорошая. Попробую на Delphi написать с использованием рекурсивной функции.

Answer (score 2):

У вас в группах g2 и g3 учится студент s1, стало быть, в ответ должна попасть строка g2, g3 (1)

Решается просто:

```
SELECT t1.group_id, 
  t2.group_id,  count(*)
FROM
  table_name t1
JOIN table_name t2
ON t2.student_id = t1.student_id AND t2.group_id > t1.group_id
GROUP BY
  t1.group_id,
  t2.group_id
```

Comment: А если в ответ должна попасть строка g1, g2, ..., gn (2). Как в таком случае будет выглядеть запрос?